# Creating Answer File For Windows 7 Deployment

Tags: windows, windows-7, activation, waik, answer-file

We use Dell Computers here and we are wanting to create a standard Desktop Image for Deployment. We only have the OEM copy of Windows 7 Professional that ships with each system.

I understand about using the AIK to create the answer file but my question is about what "Product Key" to use in the answer file, if any ??

We don't want to run into any activation issues after the fact.

Any insight would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

OEM copies of Windows each need a seperate Product ID.

If I recall correctly, you can enter system deatils and the Product IDs in WAIK and it will automatically map Product IDs to hardware.

Another option is to have the Windows 7 installer prompt the user at install time and teach the user how to find the Product ID when needed. Maybe Dell has attached the Product ID on a sticker somewhere on the systems.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there is a way to do this in fact we use this method where I work.

Dell activates windows using a certificate and a bat file on it's OEM installation disk.

first you will need to copy the OEM cert and SLP.bat files from your Dell OEM CD.The OEM Cert is located on the CD under sources\$OEM$\$$\system32\OEM and is called OEM (XrML Digital License). slp.bat is located under sources\$OEM$\$$\setup\scripts.
Then save them to your deployment share.
 Currently it should look something like this:

```
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs -ilc %windir%\system32\oem\OEM.xrm-ms
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs -ipk 32KD2-K9CTF-M3DJT-4J3WC-733WD
```

but seeing as our OEM folder will be elsewhere we will need to change it to this:

```
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs -ilc OEMLOCATION\OEM.xrm-ms
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs -ipk 32KD2-K9CTF-M3DJT-4J3WC-733WD
```

In your answer file under the OOBE pass in your answer file add:

```
 Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup_neutral
  FirstLogonCommands
   SynchronousCommand(Order="1")
     Action- AddListItem
     CommandLine- \\server\share\dellcert\makeOEM.bat
     Description- Make OEM Folder
     Order- 1
     RequiresUserInput- True
   SynchronousCommand(Order="2")
     Action- AddListItem
     CommandLine- \\server\share\DellCert\copyslp.bat
     Description- Copy slp.bat to share folder
     Order- 2
     RequiresUserInput- True
   SynchronousCommand(Order="3")
     Action- AddListItem
     CommandLine- \\server\share\DellCert\copycert.bat
     Description- Copy Dell Cert
     Order- 3
     RequiresUserInput- True
   SynchronousCommand(Order="4")
     Action- AddListItem
     CommandLine- \\server\share\DellCert\Runslp.bat
     Description- Run slp.bat
     Order- 4
     RequiresUserInput- True
```

The only way I was able to get it to work correctly was by braking it up into 4 parts as shown and set RequiresUserInput to true (don't ask me why it just would work otherewise

I actually posted more details about this else where: http://starvinggeek87.blogspot.com/2013/05/useing-windows-deployment-service-to.html